# LDAP Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, authorization

How to LDAP authentication with php

I successfully connect the ldap server in xampp.

the LDAP was bind successful

but working on this code some error shows

```
<?php


    $ldapBaseDomain = 'ou=employee,dc=domainname';
    $ldapServer = 'domainname';
    $ldapUsername = 'xxx';
    $ldapPassword = 'yyy';


if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {


    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/', $_POST['username'])) {
        die('Please enter a valid username');
    }

    if (!$ldapConnection = @ldap_connect($ldapServer)) {
        die('Could not connect to ldap server');
    }

    if (!@ldap_bind($ldapConnection, $ldapUsername, $ldapPassword)) {
        die('Could not bind to ldap server');
    }

    if (!$ldapSearch = @ldap_search($ldapConnection, $ldapBaseDomain, $_POST['username'])) {
        die('Could not complete ldap search');
    }

    $ldapCount = @ldap_count_entries($ldapConnection, $ldapSearch);

    if (!$ldapCount) {
        die('account not found');
    } else {
        if (!$ldapEntry = @ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $ldapSearch)) {
            die('Could not get ldap entry');
        }

        $distinguishedName = $ldapEntry[0]['distinguishedname'][0];

        if (empty($distinguishedName)) {
            die('Account information not found');
        }

        if(!@ldap_bind($ldapConnection, $distinguishedName, $_POST['password'])) {
            die('Password Incorrect');
        }

        echo '  <h1>Logged in successfully</h1>
                <h2>User Details</h2>';

        echo '<pre>' . print_r($ldapEntry[0], true) . '</pre>';
    }

} else {
    echo '  <form method="post">
            Username: <input name="username"><br>
            Password: <input name="password" type="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="login">
            </form>';
}

?>
```

this is error shows

> Could not complete ldap search

Any hints to solve this problem

Comment: Can you put the access logs from the LDAP server using "tail -f /var/logs/dirsrv/access"

Comment: sry i am useing windows AD so how its Possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the LDAP-search you will have to use a valid LDAP-filter. If the username is 'johndoe' you are currently simply searching for 'johndoe'. It's like doing the following SQL-search:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'johndoe';
```

YOu have to give the LDAP-Server a chance to know where to serch for the '''johndoe'''. Therefore you should use something like `sAMAccountName=johndoe` (for ActiveDirectory) or `uid=johndoe` (for OpenLdap).

For a more indepth example have a look at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592

Comment: Do you get any error-messages when you remove the ```@``` from the ```ldap_search```?

Comment: useing your example shall i declare 
$host = 'ip';
$port = 'port'; like this

Comment: So what's the exact error message? You might also want to call ```ldap_errno``` and ```ldap_error```

Comment: this is error appers  --- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''no connection'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)